# Can't Insert New Element Into XML Tree

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I am attempting to create an `XmlElement` and insert it as a **sibling** after an existing element. Here is the existing element:

```
<!--     other XHTML  precedes this -->
         <p id="testElement">Test element</p>
<!--     other XHTML follows this  -->
```

The document contains only one `p` element like the above.
Here is the element I want to add after the `p` element:

```
<div class=”CodeChar”>
  <pre/>
</div>
```

I want the resulting XHTML to look like this:

```
<!--     other XHTML  precedes this -->
         <p id="testElement">Test element</p>
         <div class=”CodeChar”>
            <pre/>
         </div>
<!--     other XHTML follows this  -->
```

I’m using the following lines of code to get a reference to the `p` element and add the div:

```
XmlElement selectedElement = null;
XmlNodeList elts = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("p");
foreach (XmlElement elt in elts)
{
    String val = elt.GetAttribute("id");
    if (val.Equals("testElement"))
    {
        selectedElement = elt;
        break;
    }
}

if (selectedElement == null)
{
    return;
}

XmlElement newDivElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("div");
newDivElement.SetAttribute("class", "CodeChar");
XmlElement preNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("pre");
newDivElement.AppendChild( preNode );
xmlDoc.InsertAfter(newDivElement, selectedElement);
```

However, the last line in the above code yields an an exception that says `“The reference node is not a child of this node.”` 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This here is wrong:

```
xmlDoc.InsertAfter(newDivElement, selectedElement);
```

You need to insert the child to the parent node of your `selectedElement`, like this:

```
var parent = selectedElement.ParentNode;
parent.InsertAfter(newDivElement, selectedElement);
```

Comment: Thanks -- works perfectly. I understand how it works now.